# How to create a chat in PHP and MySQL, with no JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chat

How can I make a chat with PHP and MySQL only, without any other language? I googled for a while, but all the solutions I found needed PHP+MySQL+AJAX/JS/jQuery. In order to keep my code as simple as possible, I'd like to only use those two languages (because idk ajax not js not jquery, LOL.). Any suggestion? I thought about making temporary records where to record the chats, but it would be way too slow, since it would require many queries. Any solution?

Comment: There are possibilities, such as an auto-reloading page, but to do any sort of decent chat without Javascript is unreasonable.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please read the [faq]. This question is too broad to answer simply, which is why it's being downvoted.

Comment: You'll have to learn JS, otherwise you'll end up with a quite clumsy system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any solution would be too slow in this case.

See, the core nature of chat is real-time (or close to) updating: you'd want to see the message written by someone as fast as possible (if not, it's a forum territory, not chat). There are several methods of dealing with this problem, but they all involve JavaScript (as you need to update the page shown to your users).

Of course, you might make your page auto-refreshing (with `meta http-equiv="refresh"`), but it would drastically increase the load on your server - and it will still behave like a forum, just on the 'refresh steroids'. )

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking for it not feasible.

You need some method of sending the user's chat message back to the server.  Without AJAX, you will be required to submit the entire page to the server every time the user makes a comment, then download the entire page as a response (which is a HUGE drain on your traffic).

Then, there's the fact that users won't be able to see any other comments until the page is refreshed, which means either refreshing the entire page at some determined interval (and risk losing the user's partially written comment), or just waiting for them to make a comment.

So, the bottom line is, you CANNOT do this without AJAX.